# Data loss in sql server after closing winform application , autosave option

Tags: sql, c, sql-server-2005, autosave, data-loss

Is there any AutoSave kind of option in SQL Server. Like i came to know from a chap that when the data is saved into a database via an application then after closing the application the database loses its data, & the data had to be entered again into the database which was an error so to correct this, the autosave option of the database have to be turned ON.

do this exist in SQL Server? if yes, then i think it is always ON by default, because when we save any data in a sql server database from a winform .net application then the data is not lost even after closing the application and running it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such problem and so no fix.

This is rubbish unless the client or database *code* is at fault. It is not a database engine issue.

Examples:

- leaving client side transactions open which are rolled back when the client closes
- implicit transactions enabled which is *not* the default (which are also rolled back when the client closes)

Edit:

Or are you [using temp tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295748/trigger-and-transactions-on-temporary-tables) as per a previous question?

Comment: sir, actually my co-programmer who uses Foxpro told me this? so i thought of confirming it , are you sure about Foxpro also?

Comment: @sqlchild: I answered for SQL Server: this is what you asked, I've never used Foxpro.